# Is there an idiomatic equivalent in German for “have other fish to fry”?

Tags: idiom

Is there an idiomatic equivalent in German for “have other fish to fry”?

> have other fish to fry: "To have more important things to do"

As an anecdote I want to mention that in the two romance languages I am familiar with, this idiom is related to cats:

In French: avoir d'autres chats à fouetter- to have other cats to whip 
In Italian: avere altre gatte da pelare - to have other cats to skin

Comment: Schlichtweg: *Ich habe wichtigere Dinge zu tun* ;p

Comment: Actually, since the answers are a bit off-topic or doesn't say anything else than a literal translation for "to have more important things to do", I would say: No, there isn't an idiom!

Comment: @ Em1, you are right, a correct answer would be "no there isn't an idiom, some literal translation are such and such

Comment: Not strictly the same, but in *nicht meine Baustelle* the more important things are implied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there *is* an "animalistic" idom for "more important things"

If someone has no time for you and seems to have an important business, you can ask ironically:

> Was hast du denn noch für Igel zu bürsten?

See e.g. http://echt-gothsch.de/pages/redensarten.php

Comment: I've also heard “ich habe noch andere Igel zu bürsten” – frequently, but afaicr only from members of one family, so that may not count for much.

Comment: What is the literal translation to English?

Comment: "I have to brush some other hedgehogs." Never heard that one, though.

Comment: I agree, the phrase isn't used very frequently. But it is funny and I'll try to employ it myself more often :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Ich habe Wichtigeres zu tun.

Answer (score 0):

> Ich habe besseres zu tun.
>
> Ich habe wichtigeres vor.

(`besseres` and `wichtigeres` may have to be capitalized under Neue Deutsche Rechtschreibung. Fight the power!)

Comment: It strikes me as curious that there seems to be a gap here in German vis-à-vis other European languages. Perhaps "ich habe mit dir noch ein Hühnchen zu rupfen" (I've got a bone to pick with you) diverged from a now-forgotten ancestor that did serve such a purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Nicht wirklich passend, aber angrenzend:

> Ich habe noch ein  <strike>heißes</strike> Eisen im Feuer.

Ein Eisen im Feuer zu haben wird aber benutzt um eine weitere Option, die man hat, zu beschreiben; nicht eine Pflicht, die man erledigen muss.

Es könnte also in manchen Fällen passen, aber nicht in allen.

Comment: "noch ein Eisen im Feuer" <> "ein heißes Eisen anfassen"

Comment: Mit kalter Fusion natürlich auch kalte Eisen im Feuer ...